# SignalR Hub with Windows Azure SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, azure

I've been a developer for a long time but I've never laid my hands on sql databases (I know, not smart of me). Anyway, I need to a create a databse on windows azure sql, design the tables and columns, and then access it using (Entity Framework , Entity Client, etc) from my ASP.NET Web Application.

I've followed this tutorial to create the database http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-database/ , I successfully created everything, just don't know how to connect to it now. Also, when I click on Manage on windows azure, I can see that the sql database (not the server) is prompting me to create a database ... inside my database which confused me a lot.

I've had a look at these, still not sure if that's what I'm looking for
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951633.aspx

All I need is a simply tutorial that would explain how do I connect to my database in order to design it (columns and tables), and then how do I access, read, write data from an ASP.NET Web Application

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (I have 2012 installed as well), and can download whichever tool that would allow me to connect that dabatase.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer is not supported in Azure SQL..

You can instead us this link : https://SERVERNAMEGOESHERE.database.windows.net/

that contains an online database editor, or you could use a localdatabase first and then deploy through management studio

if you need your connectionstring later you can get this through windows azure portal --> your database --> Quick glance --> SHOW Connectionstring

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying this now. So this will allow me to design tables and columns in the database. How do I later access them from my asp.net web application (it's a signalR hub) ?

Comment: it will yes. and when you are going to use it in a asp.net web application you can just use an ORM like entity framework with the connectionstring found in windows azure portal :)

Comment: ok any tutorial how can I setup an ORM like entity framework please ?